# how to remove vertical gaps when using floats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I used `float: left` for my `div`s but vertical gap created. 
How to remove gaps on top of `div` 5 and 8?

Please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sPqC/8/) Example.

Note: I need responsive (change result width). Ordering is important, so [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhaU/1/) not acceptable. I will use bootstrap and `col-lg-6` in real project. Contents may be dynamic. JS solution is acceptable.

Comment: You cant do this in `CSS` use http://masonry.desandro.com/. I use it all the time for things like this, its very good. Other then that, you could use the columns and insert elements depending on there height, so if left is bigger then right place next element in the right etc. I have done it like this before and it works. Will only work for fixed heights if your ordering by dates etc.

Comment: Tangential remark: I would **really** love a CSS property to change the stack orientation from horizontal to vertical; i.e. basically what OP wants to achieve. Elements would then stack in a column instead of next to eachother, and if it needs to be wrapped, it creates a second column instead of a row. I'm honestly surprised this has not yet been implemented in all this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not css pure solution, I suggest you use something like http://masonry.desandro.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

check this use css3 column property and adjust as you want

http://jsfiddle.net/6sPqC/14/

```
HTML
<div class="a">
    <div class="a1">1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </div>
    <div class="a2">2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 </div>
    <div class="a3">3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </div>
    <div class="a4">4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 </div>
    <div class="a5">5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 </div>
    <div class="a6">6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 </div>
    <div class="a7">7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 </div>
    <div class="a8">8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 88 </div>
<div>


CSS
.a{
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
.a div{

   width: 100%;
   margin: 5%;
}


.a1,.a6{background-color: red;}
.a2,.a7{background-color: blue;}
.a3,.a8{background-color: green;}
.a4,.a9{background-color: gray;}
.a5,.a10{background-color: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen due to your div a3 have less content due to which you a3 float left with your div a4  and cover gap upto white space and then your next div 5 float left. you have two option to resolve it 1st you apply content min and max length restriction for div. if content is static then adjust your content according to div 
2nd option is create a new class with float:none property and apply it on that div after that you need to drop in this example we need drop on div 3 .

but there is no alternate solution for that